# Не отображает компонент в react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

пытаюсь вывести компонент через алерт по нажатии кнопки, но что-то не получается, что же делать?

```
function Mailbox(props) {
    const unreadmessages = props.unreadmessages;
    <div>
        {unreadmessages.length > 0 &&
            <h1>У вас {unreadmessages.length} непрочитанных</h1>
        }
        {unreadmessages.length <= 0 &&
            <h1>У вас нет непрочитанных сообщений</h1>
        }
    </div>
}

const messages = [];
const mailbox = <Mailbox unreadmessages={messages} />;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showMessages = this.showMessages.bind(this);
    }


    showMessages() {
        alert(mailbox);
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <button onClick={this.showMessages}>Посмотреть все сообщения</button>
        );
    }

}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')

    );
```

Comment: вместо компонента выводится "[object Object]"

Comment: Mailbox не содержит return

Comment: @СергейКоновалов ошибка не ушла

Comment: В алерт нельзя выводить блоки. Создайте свой кастомный `div` и стилизуйте его под алерт

Comment: @meine Извините, но у меня не так много опыта, и я не представляю как реализовать то, что вы описали выше. Не могли бы Вы написать то что вы предложили

Answer (score 0):

Решил ошибку. просто в состоянии компонента App создал метод mailbox у которого нулевое значение, а по нажатию кнопки менял состояние и выводил комопонет на страницу, правда алерт пришлось убрать